# Opengraph aggregation preview not working

Tags: facebook-opengraph, preview

I have been struggling for 2 days trying to get the application preview in the app dashboard to work with sample data.  I have successfully created an object (level), and an action (run).  I have successfully configured 2 different aggregations (My favorite level & My favorite levels).  I have created and debugged sample objects and actions for the aggregations...but I still see only a "generic" preview of my aggregation.  I have tried in both Chrome and Safari.

What the heck am I doing wrong?

this is what I see: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35391195/OG_testing/aggregation_preview.png